# How do I export a lxc container?

Tags: linux, lxc

Is it possible to export a `lxc` container to another machine? There are some tools like `lxc-snap` and `lxc-clone` will those help in exporting to another system? Can I copy paste the rootfs folder or is there a standard way of doing this?

Comment: I thought this is what `publish` is for. Then you can import it on another machine...

Comment: Haven't used that. Simple copy paste works usually with LXC. It abstracts an OS as a folder so its as easy as copy paste along with a bunch of config files.

Comment: https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/try-it/ has a basic tutorial on publishing and importing, and you can find info to your heart's content at https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/04/01/lxd-2-0-image-management-512/

Comment: Thats an awesome link! Will go through it. Back in the days I had this problem, there was no resources I could find. However it helped me learn some new stuff like `chrooting` etc which I have provided as an alternate option.

Comment: LXC/D 2.0 is a big step forward!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think `lxc-clone` and `lxc-snap` are supposed to be used for moving containers to a new machine. [The rationale for these commands](https://s3hh.wordpress.com/2013/05/06/introducing-lxc-snap/), according to one of the LXC developers, is:

> One of the obvious use cases of these snapshot clones is to support
>   incremental development of rootfs images. Make some changes, snapshot,
>   make some more changes, snapshot, revert…

There is no mention ever of an *export to a different machine*...

At the same time, I have successfully ported a Debian LXC from a Debian machine to an Arch Linux machine, by first creating a Debian LXC container, without any customization, then by copying over to the new machine the `config, fstab, lxcname.log` files and the `rootfs` directory. You may try it, like I did, but ... YMMV.

Comment: Awesome! I had the same thought. I was thinking of copying over the rootfs as well but wanted to see if a tool exists. Interesting to see config fstab and lxcname.log in that list of files to be copied. I will select this as the best answer unless someone suggest a tool which apparently doesn't exist atm :)

Answer (score 1):

I run `lxc` containers on `btrfs` volumes so I can snapshot them easily with `btrfs sub snap`

These can be moved to a remote `btrfs` filesystem more quickly than with `rsync` using:

```
btrfs send /my/snapshot | ssh user@host.com "btrfs receive /my/destination"
```

`btrfs` is intelligent with snapshots & does not include virtual filesystems [`proc run sys`]. Transfering incremental snapshots are also possible.

When moving snapshots to a **non** `btrfs` filesystem:

- Mount the remote destination as an `sshfs` filesystem & `cd` to the mount
- Stop the container & create a `tar.xz` archive of the container

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just copy the filesystem and make the relevant changes as mentioned in the above post to make everything work fine. Initially I did that and made it working.

I always have problems with NAT in LXC Containers, so if you are a light weight user, you can also just `chroot` into the system. Currently I use `lxc-templates` to create a copy of my desired OS and then `chroot` into that system to do my stuff. I don't need a virtualization in my use case. The idea is just simple (not in terms of implementation) that it can be ported easily.